# math js - position of variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

My first question here...

any suggestions about the non working js below would be appreciated.. thanks in advance.

Should i be adding the variables on the top to begin with?

I assume this is something relatively easy to solve but it will mean great deal to me..

```js
var k = $("#rd").val();
var k1

if (k < 120) {
    k1 = 1.2;
} else if (k > 120) {
    k1 = 1.1;
}

var g = $("#dow").val();
var g1
if (g = 6) {
    g1 = 1.4;
} else if (g = 5) {
    g1 = 1.2;
}
else if (g = 0) {
    g1 = 1.1;
}
else {
    g1 = 0.7;
}

var a = $("moy").val();
var a1
if (a = 8) {
    a1 = 1.1;
} else if (a = 7) {
    a1 = 1.2;
}
else if (a = 6) {
    a1 = 1.1;
}
else if (a = 5) {
    a1 = 1.1;
}

else {
    a1 = 0.7;
}

document.getElementById("demoo").innerHTML = k1 + g1 + a1;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="rd">100</p>
<p id="moy">8</p>
<p id="dow">6</p>
<p id="demoo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example, please make sure you have jQuery library added somewhere in your page.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var k =parseInt($("#rd").html());
     var k1; //better to have ;
     if (k < 120) {
    k1 = 1.2;
} else if (k > 120) {

   k1 = 1.1;
}

   var g = parseInt($("#dow").html());

     var g1;
   if (g == 6) { // not = must be == 
    g1 = 1.4;
} else if (g == 5) {
    g1 = 1.2;
}
 else if (g == 0) {
   g1 = 1.1;
}
else {
    g1 = 0.7;
}        
   var a = parseInt($("#moy").html()); //forget # here 

     var a1;
    if (a == 8) {
     console.log(a);
    a1 = 1.1;
} else if (a == 7) {
    a1 = 1.2;
}
 else if (a == 6) {
   a1 = 1.1;
}
 else if (a == 5) {
   a1 = 1.1;
}

else {
    a1 = 0.7;
} 
   var total = k1+g1+a1; // better to assign to  var var
  document.getElementById("demoo").innerHTML = total.toFixed(1); // aslo can use $('#demoo').html(total.toFixed(1))
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works in fiddle but i could not get it to work on my wordpress site, dont know why..  http://ulan.be/aaa/  TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):367)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
(anonymous) @ (index):367
i @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
fireWith @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
ready @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
K @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2

Comment: would you try this  $('#demoo').html(total.toFixed(1));  instead of  document.getElementById("demoo").innerHTML = total.toFixed(1); and let me know if that works

Comment: Also <p id="demoo"></p> does get remove when page is loaded even though page source has it. It would be good idea to have some default value in it or have &nbsp;<p id="demoo">&nbsp;</p> . Null pointer exception mean it did not find that dom.

Comment: works now - you have been of unbelievable help Santosh, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
.val()
```

is used to get the value from a text input and not in cases you used it.

To get the text content inside html tags use jQuery .text() method:

```
$("#rd").text( )
```

It is also recommended to convert the text to number first with parseFloat:

```
var k = parseFloat($("#rd").text())
```

Furthermore, I would recommend you adding some code, that will determine k1 in case of k=120

I'm using my phone right now, so I wasn't able to check if it works correctly. Please, tell me if further problems occur.

Comment: Also, "moy" is missing a "#".

Comment: Yeah, and use "==" in if statements (e.g. if(a==6) { } )

Answer (score 0):

Double equal

```
if (a ==
```

and perhaps syntaxes like semicolon
in var g1;